# using event listener to reverse an animation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code that I got from github to show a random clip from my twitch channele.
I edited a bit of the code to do some animations as an intro before showing the clip, and an event listener code to call out when the clip has ended.
the thing is I didn't know how to make the event listener load a code to reverse the intro animation

here's the code

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script>
      // hey streamer! all of the config stuff is here
      //import {BROADCASTER_NAME} from 'D:\OBSStreamingshit\TwitchSOClipplayer\Cinst.js';
      const CLIENT_ID = "...";
      const CLIENT_SECRET = "...";
      const BROADCASTER_NAME = "HXS01";

      const TOP_OR_RANDOM = "top";
      const VOLUME_PERCENT = 50;
      const SHOW_CLIP_CREATORS = "true";
      // TOP_OR_RANDOM can be either "top" to prioritise top clips or "random" to get random clips out of your top 1000
      // note that "random" clip mode requires a tiny bit of buffer time when the page is first loaded to collect a list of clips

      // below is just all the code that makes this work. once you've configured the settings above, you're good to go!
      // -ShaderWave

      // Utility functions
      async function authenticatedFetch(url, options) {
        options = options || {};
        options.headers = options.headers || {};

        options.headers["Client-ID"] = CLIENT_ID;
        options.headers["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${
          (await getTwitchCredentials()).access_token
        }`;

        return await fetch(url, options);
      }

      let OAUTH = null;
      async function getTwitchCredentials() {
        if (OAUTH) return OAUTH;

        const response = await fetch(
          `https://id.twitch.tv/oauth2/token?client_id=${CLIENT_ID}&client_secret=${CLIENT_SECRET}&grant_type=client_credentials`,
          {
            method: "POST",
          }
        );
        OAUTH = await response.json();
        return OAUTH;
      }

      let BROADCASTER_ID = null;
      async function getBroadcasterId() {
        if (BROADCASTER_ID) return BROADCASTER_ID;

        const response = await authenticatedFetch(
          `https://api.twitch.tv/helix/users?login=${BROADCASTER_NAME}`
        );
        BROADCASTER_ID = (await response.json()).data[0].id;
        return BROADCASTER_ID;
      }

      let CLIPS_PAGINATION = null;
      async function getTopClips() {
        let response = await authenticatedFetch(
          `https://api.twitch.tv/helix/clips?first=100&broadcaster_id=${await getBroadcasterId()}${
            CLIPS_PAGINATION ? `&after=${CLIPS_PAGINATION}` : ""
          }`
        );
        let body = await response.json();

        CLIPS_PAGINATION = body.pagination.cursor;
        return body;
      }

      async function getRandomClips() {
        let clips = [];

        const max = 10;
        let pagination = null;
        for (let i = 0; i < max; i++) {
          // top 1000 clips
          let response = await authenticatedFetch(
            `https://api.twitch.tv/helix/clips?first=100&broadcaster_id=${await getBroadcasterId()}${
              pagination ? `&after=${pagination}` : ""
            }`
          );
          let body = await response.json();

          pagination = body.pagination.cursor;
          clips = clips.concat(body.data);

          const status = document.getElementById("status");
          status.innerText =
            "Loading Clips: " + Math.floor(((i + 1) / max) * 100) + "%";
        }

        return clips;
      }

      function getClipStreamURL(clip) {
        let thumbPart = clip.thumbnail_url.split("-preview-");
        return thumbPart[0] + ".mp4";
      }

      let CLIPS_TO_PLAY = [];
      let CLIP_PLAYING = null;

      async function setupPlayer() {
        const clips =
          TOP_OR_RANDOM == "top"
            ? (await getTopClips()).data
            : await getRandomClips();
        let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * Object.keys(clips).length);
        const clip = clips[Object.keys(clips)[random]];
        const player = document.getElementById("player");
        const container = document.getElementById("container");
        const img = document.getElementsByClassName("bd");
        //const aEnd = document(".bu");
        player.load();

        player.loop = false;
        player.controls = false;
        player.volume = VOLUME_PERCENT / 100;
        player.pause();
        player.src = getClipStreamURL(clip);
        // img.addEventListener("animationend", () => {
        //  console.log("animationsended");
        // });
        player.addEventListener("ended", () => {
          console.log("ended");
          load(".bu");
          //   player.style.display = "none";
        });
      }

      function run() {
        setupPlayer();
      }

      window.addEventListener("load", run);
      //<video autoplay loop={false} id="player" style="width: 70%; height: 70%; position: absolute; top: 125; left: 300; z-index: -1;"></video>
    </script>
    <div class="container" id="container">
      <video autoplay loop="{false}" id="player" class="vid"></video>

      <img src="Border up.png" class="bu" />
      <img src="Border down.png" class="bd" />

      <div id="overlay" class="overlayText"></div>
      <h1 id="status" class="statusText"></h1>
    </div>
  </body>

  <head>
    <style>
      @import url(https://db.onlinewebfonts.com/c/03d33d67fd07fb2d31001eb9f90d58bf?family=Posterama+2001+W04+SemiBold);
      .statusText {
        position: absolute;
        font-family: "Posterama 2001 W04", SemiBold;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

        color: white;

        padding: 4px 8px 4px 8px;
        border-radius: 4px;
      }

      .statusText.hide {
        display: none;
      }

      .container {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }

      .overlayText {
        position: absolute;
        /*These calcs are used to track the bottom corner of the video as it holds its aspect ratio while the window is resized*/
        top: calc(
          (100vh - min(100vh/9, 100vw/16) * 9) / 2 + min(100vh/9, 100vw/16) * 9 -
            40px
        );
        left: calc((100vw - min(100vh/9, 100vw/16) * 16) / 2 + 1.2vw);
        color: white;
        font-size: large;
      }

      .vid {
        width: 70%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 170px;
        left: 10px;
        transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
        animation-name: vidT;
        animation-duration: 3s;
        border-radius: 50px;
        /* animation-delay: 1s; */
      }
      .bd {
        position: absolute;
        top: 351px;
        left: 10px;
        width: 70%;
        transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
        animation-name: lower;
        animation-duration: 3s;
        /* animation-delay: 1s; */
      }
      .bu {
        position: absolute;
        top: -24px;
        left: 10px;
        width: 70%;
        transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
        animation-name: upper;
        animation-duration: 3s;
        /* animation-delay: 1s; */

        /* animation-delay: 2s; */
      }
      /* .bdr {
        position: absolute;
        top: 351px;
        left: 10px;
        width: 70%;
        transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
        animation-name: lower;
        animation-duration: 0.7s;
        animation-direction: reverse;
      } */

      @keyframes upper {
        0% {
          top: 1000px;
        }
        25% {
          top: 320px;
        }
        50% {
          top: 320px;
        }
        75% {
          top: 320px;
        }
        86% {
          top: 320px;
        }
        100% {
          top: -24px;
        }
      }
      @keyframes lower {
        0% {
          top: 600px;
        }
        25% {
          top: -95px;
        }
        50% {
          top: -95px;
        }
        75% {
          top: -95px;
        }
        86% {
          top: -95px;
        }
        100% {
          top: 352px;
        }
      }
      @keyframes vidT {
        0% {
          transform: scaleY(0%);
        }
        25% {
          transform: scaleY(0%);
        }
        50% {
          transform: scaleY(0%);
        }
        75% {
          transform: scaleY(0%);
        }
        85% {
          transform: scaleY(0%);
        }
        100% {
          transform: scaleY(100%);
        }
      }
    </style>
  </head>
</html>
```

the event listener is on the line 124

I would apreacate it if you can tell me how to do it step by step because I'm new

Comment: Thanks for posting a snippet, however, Stack Overflow does not have line numbers on snippets, so any chance you could just add a comment as a marker?